# How to add a JComboBox on an IToolBarManager

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, jcombobox

I am developing an Eclipse plug in and try to put a `JComboBox` on an [`IToolBarManager`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjface%2Faction%2FIToolBarManager.html) and add `ActionListener` to it, so I can handle the `JComboBox` selection.

Can anyone please help me with that?

Comment: *"and try to put"*  What happened when you tried it?  We are not psychic, so more detail is better than less.  BTW - it seems from the docs for `IToolBarManager` that it is part of SWT.  SWT should provide a similar component, but SWT & Swing don't mix.

Comment: @AndrewThompson, Hold on, let me give Mrs. Cleo a call.

Comment: apologize for my short description. On an IToolBarManager object you can add IContributionItem items or IAction actions. So I do not now how to add a JComboBox using those ones, so I actually did not do much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There may be a better solution, but I have used the following method:

```
IToolBarManager mgr = this.getViewSite().getActionBars().getToolBarManager();
IContributionItem comboCI = new ControlContribution("test") {
        protected Control createControl(Composite parent) {

            final Combo c = new Combo(parent, SWT.READ_ONLY);
            c.add("one");
            c.add("two");
            c.add("three");
            c.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
                 public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                     c.add("four");
                  }
                  });
            return c;
        }
    };        

    mgr.add(comboCI);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Phil. I think this will do the job!